# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when using sqlalchemy and pandas df.to_sql

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to read using sqlalchemy and then insert into Oracle DB. pd.read_sql_query works fine and when I execute **display (df)**, I get following result.

```
ldate           lid             lkey                 act__c     name            c_status__c cre_dt                  cre_by      l_cre_dt                l_cre_by
2020-08-12  a1234A6788qRstuYGE                                  Test name LLC   Prospect    2020-08-10 09:14:42.0   Test Usr    2020-08-12 11:48:16.0   Test Usr
2020-08-13  a1234A6788qRstuYGE                                  Test name LLC   Prospect    2020-08-10 09:14:42.0   Test Usr    2020-08-12 11:48:16.0   Test Usr
2020-10-09  a1234A6788qRstuYGE                      123456789   Test name LLC   Prospect    2020-08-10 09:14:42.0   Test Usr    2020-08-12 11:48:16.0   Test Usr
2020-10-10  a1234A6788qRstuYGE                      123456789   Test name LLC   Client      2020-08-10 09:14:42.0   Test Usr    2020-08-12 11:48:16.0   Test Usr
2020-10-10  a1234A6788qRstuYGE 200140958CONTRACT1   123456789   Test name LLC   Client      2020-08-10 09:14:42.0   Test Usr    2020-10-10 18:28:24.0   Test Usr
2020-10-11  a1234A6788qRstuYGE                      123456789   Test name LLC   Client      2020-08-10 09:14:42.0   Test Usr    2020-08-12 11:48:16.0   Test Usr
2020-10-11  a1234A6788qRstuYGE 200140958CONTRACT1   123456789   Test name LLC   Client      2020-08-10 09:14:42.0   Test Usr    2020-10-10 18:28:24.0   Test Usr
2020-11-01  a1234A6788qRstuYGE                      123456789   Test name LLC   Client      2020-08-10 09:14:42.0   Test Usr    2020-08-12 11:48:16.0   Test Usr
```

and subsequently when we issue df.to_sql('test_insert', conn, if_exists='replace'). I get following error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

## my code below for your review

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

test_query = """
SELECT * from TBL
"""
conn = create_engine('redshift+psycopg2://testredshitserver:1234/testdb',connect_args={'sslmode': 'prefer'})
df = pd.read_sql_query(test_query,conn)
display (df)
# Here is the issue
df.to_sql('test_insert', conn, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: Anyone please... @Parfait , can you please help on this issue

Comment: Adjust your test_query to return just a few rows and verify that the resulting DataFrame will reproduce the issue. Then use `df.to_pickle("pickled.gz")` to dump it into a file and post a download link for that file.

Comment: @GordThompson. Is it possible to share the pickled.gz privately?

Comment: @GordThompson uploaded. Thx sir

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using SQLite (`sqlite:///:memory:`). Can you try using that connection URI and see if it behaves any better for you?

Comment: @GordThompson sadly i need to load this into Oracle DB, which is our DB

Comment: The test code I'm using is [here](https://pastebin.com/GQB7Uh4X).

Comment: Testing with SQLite is for diagnostic purposes. Using your sample DataFrame, `to_sql` also works fine for me with `oracle+cx_oracle://`. If you're trying to write to Oracle then why are you using `redshift+psycopg2://`?

Comment: yup.. i got that covered.. but i do get this now "DistributionNotFound: The 'packaging' distribution was not found and is required by the application".. .. any ideas